# Rails + Paperclip Error! undefined method `has_attached_file'

Tags: angularjs, ruby-on-rails-4, paperclip

I have problem whit the next code:

```
$scope.load_icons = function(file){
  filename =  file[0].name;
  filenamearray = filename.split('.');
  extencion = filenamearray[filenamearray.length-1];
  console.log(user_profiling);
  if(extencion==='png'||extencion==='gif'||extencion==='jpg'||extencion==='PNG'||extencion==='GIF'||extencion==='JPG'){
    $upload.upload({
      url: '/user_icons.json',
      data: {},
      file: file
    }).progress(function(evt){

      console.log(evt);

    }).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {

      console.log(data);

    }).error(function(data, status, headers, config){

      console.log(data);

    });
  }
}
```

user_icon.rb

```
    class UserIcon < ActiveRecord::Base
      has_attached_file :image, :styles => { :d512 => "512x512>", :d256 => "256x256", :d256 => "256x256", :d128 => "128x128", :d64 => "64x64", :d32 => "32x32" }, :default_url => "/marker/:style/missing.png"
      validates_attachment_content_type :image, :content_type => /\Aimage\/.*\Z/
    end
```

user_icons_controller.rb

```
class UserIconsController < ApplicationController
  skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token

  def create

    @icon = UserIcon.new(params)



    respond_to do |format|
      if @icon.save
        format.html { redirect_to @icon, notice: 'Category was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @icon }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @icon.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  private
    def icons_params
      params.require(:image).permit(:tempfile)
    end


end
```

I require loading and resize images to be icons (markers) but I get the following error:

[image]

And I keep in the URL database of the generated images.

Thank you very much for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved delete the model and re create correctly...

```
rails g model user_icons user_id:integer url:string image:attachment
```

I need declare the param to file upload and used this in my paperclip model..

rookie mistake!! ;(